# How to copy contents of a directory recursively without maintaining the directory hierarchy?

Tags: bash, shell

I am using Bash and I want to copy the contents of all subdirectories in the directories into a single flat-directory.

Here is an example. The input directory is:

```
xyz
--x1
  --y1
    --test1.txt
    --test2.txt
    --image1.jpg
--x2
  --test3.txt
```

And I want the resultant directory to be:

```
abc 
--test1.txt
--test2.txt
--test3.txt
--image1.jpg
```

Are there a combination of flags with `cp` command that can be used to achieve the above? The name of the files are always unique.

Comment: Is there a possibility that two folders contain files with the same name? Or are names unique?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: The name of the files in the folders are unique always. I will update the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mkdir and find:

```
mkdir -p abc
find ./xyz -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} ./abc
```

Comment: Or, if your `cp` supports the `-t` option: `find ./xyz -type f -exec cp -t ./abc {} +`